# How to maintain idempotency in a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I have operations following few operations to be performed through recipes

1. creation of database on a remote node,
2. running few mysql scripts
3. Extraction of few packages (tar and zip)
4. Executing .bin or .sh files

What can be best way to manage such operations in chef recipes while avoiding bash/execute resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using appropriate Chef resources, you get this idempotency already for many use cases.

1. [mysql_database](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database#database) handles data base creation for you.
2. Running "few mysql scripts" could be guarded by [not_if/only_if](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#guards).
3. Extraction of packages: [ark](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/ark)
4. Executing scripts: Again guards or if appropriate as a service of your operating system. If you transform these scripts into chef recipes, it might make your life also easier.